# Take last hour and group it by 1 minute

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was wondering if you can help me write a query that should just SELECT count(*) but only include data from last hour and group it by minute.

So I have a table that has a `createdts` so I have the date there. I just want to see how many entries I have in the last hour, but group `COUNT(*)` per minute.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable 
WHERE createdts >= now()::date - interval '1 hour'
GROUP BY 'every minute'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DATE_TRUNC()` does this:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('minute', createdts), COUNT(*)
FROM mytable 
WHERE createdts >= now()::date - interval '1 hour'
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('minute', createdts)
ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('minute', createdts);
```